# powershell delete everything before : after start of a line, on each line

Tags: powershell, split

I have text file containing IP ranges.

On each line there is an IP range like `:64.76.139.160-64.76.139.167` starting with a colon, as you can see.

I want to delete everything before the colon after the start of a line, and on each line do the same thing, using powershell.

From this picture it is easier to see what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp2Oe.jpg

I tried store the text file into a variable and this code:

```
$data.split(':')[1].split(' ')
```

Which deleted everything after start of a file.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you saving the output to a new file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need something like this:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\file.txt) {
    if($line -match ":"){
        $line = $line.split(":")[1]
    }

    write-output $line
}
```

Not sure how you want the output, but you just need to loop through the lines of the file and use the `split()` operator.

If you wanted to keep the colon, you simply need to modify the last line like so:

```
":$line"
```

Comment: You'd need to do string addition or something of that nature.  `Write-Output` is unnecessary as anything laid bare will be on the output stream.  `":$line"` would be sufficient.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Thanks, I edited my post. I didn't mean to use `write-output` initially, I planned to edit that part with writing to a file or something but OP never responded.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a regular expression replace, something like this:

```
$data -replace '^[^:]+:', ''
```

Comment: Having an empty block after replace is unnecessary, FYI.  You can get away with `$data -replace '^[^:]+:'`